# how do you write a map function to convert a list of integers to a list of strings?

Tags: python-3.x

i'm having trouble figure this out

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> i = [1,2,3]
>>> s = [str(x) for x in i]
>>> s
['1', '2', '3']
```

Or:

```
>>> i = [1,2,3]
>>> s = map(lambda x: str(x), i)
>>> list(s)
['1', '2', '3']
```

Or, as RoadRunner suggested in a comment, here's shorthand for the map I just mentioned above:

```
>>> i = [1,2,3]
>>> s = map(str, i)
>>> list(s)
['1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: Can just do `map(str, i)`. No need for `lambda`.